# How to create an Instagram location linked to a Facebook place/page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation, instagram, instagram-api

I have a Facebook page with a Facebook place.
If I use its Facebook ID in the Instagram API /locations/search as a FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID I receive this response:

```
    {
      "data" : [],
      "meta" : {
        "code" : 200
      }
    }
```

meaning that I have no location on Instagram linked to this Facebook place ID.
How can I create an Instagram location so that my Facebook place is connected to the new Instagram location?
Assuming I can create the Instagram location (by creating a photo and creating the location), should I name the location with the same name of my Facebook place/page? Is that enough?

Comment: What's your facebook page id?
Are there any photo shared in your place?

Comment: This one for example: 579155608825108 
I don't know if there are photos in this place, I suppose not. 
I'm just trying to understand which one it's correct: 
1) post a photo on Instagram geotagging it by searching the Facebook place name, in order to create an Instagram location linked with the Facebook place
2) post a photo on Instagram creating a new location with the same name of the Facebook Place